# Python Beautiful Soup Scraping, Newegg

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm brand new to python and figured I'd try to learn making a web scrape. So I'm trying to scrape a Newegg website for graphics cards, but seem to have some trouble with errors. All I want to do is grab the data and import it into a cvs file that I can view. but it seems that if I comment that out i get another error, I seem to not be able to figure it out. Any help is appreciated!

File "webScrape.py", line 32, in 
    price = price_container[0].text.strip("|")
IndexError: list index out of range

```
# import beautiful soup 4 and use urllib to import urlopen
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

# url where we will grab the product data
my_url = 'https://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspxSubmit=ENE&DEPA=0&Order=BESTMATCH&Description=graphics+card&ignorear=0&N=-1&isNodeId=1'

# open connection and grab the URL page information, read it, then close it
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

# parse html from the page
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

# find each product within the item-container class
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"item-container"})

# write a file named products.csv with the data returned
filename = "products.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")

# create headers for products
headers = "price, product_name, shipping\n"

f.write("")

# define containers based on location on webpage and their DOM elements
for container in containers:
       price_container = container.findAll("li", {"class":"price-current"})
       price = price_container[0].text.strip("|")

       title_container = container.findAll("a", {"class":"item-title"})
       product_name = title_container[0].text

       shipping_container = container.findAll("li",{"class":"price-ship"})
       shipping = shipping_container[0].text.strip()

        f.write(price + "," + product_name.replace(",", "|") + "," + shipping + "\n")

f.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write to a dataframe and that is easy to export to csv. I have added an additional class selector of `.list-wrap`  to `titles` to ensure all lists are the same length.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import pandas as pd

def main():

    url = 'https://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&DEPA=0&Order=BESTMATCH&Description=+graphics+cards&N=-1&isNodeId=1'
    res = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, "lxml")
    prices = soup.select('.price-current')
    titles = soup.select('.list-wrap .item-title')
    shipping = soup.select('.price-ship')   
    items = list(zip(titles,prices, shipping))   
    results = [[title.text.strip(),re.search('\$\d+.\d+',price.text.strip()).group(0),ship.text.strip()] for title, price,ship in items]

    df = pd.DataFrame(results,columns=['title', 'current price', 'shipping cost'])
    df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Data.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8',index = False )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked great, Anyways to loop it for multiple pages?

Comment: Sorry just seen this. Re-write the above slightly as functions to be called when looping over pages. I will have a look later today.